Java - Thread pool that scales up to a maximum and down to a minimum
Is it possible to have a thread pool that starts with 4 worker threads. Let’s suppose the 4 threads start out as idle. Eventually, they pick up work, I don’t know, maybe from network sockets that they may be listening on and they all become busy, I would like at this point to increase the pool by adding let’s say four more workers to a total of eight. Then the threads will become idle meaning that they go back to listening on a port until more work arrives. At any point in time some of them may become idle for a period of time, let’s say 60 seconds. At this time I would like to reduce the pool back to 4 by terminating / interrupting some of the idle threads.
In summary the pool starts with 4 but if they all become active at any one time I would like 4 more for a total of 8 as a maximum. Then eventually shrink down to the original size.
Right now a have a fixed size thread pool.

This sounds pointless; idle threads have effectively zero overhead. If you're talking about, say, 5000 threads, you're on to something, but, "4 to 8"? That's nothing. What's the maximum # of threads you want? The point of limiting it is simply that its better to do 1000 jobs with 100 threads (Because at least then jobs finish in batches of roughly a 100) than a thousand (Because then none complete until the end, possibly). Whatever your max is - just have a constant pool with that many.

By the way, if your tasks involve blocking (are not CPU-bound) then you may be able to ditch the thread pooling and instead use virtual threads.

I think rzwitserloot is basically correct, for thread pools under 10 or 20 threads it's kinda a pointless optimization on modern hardware.  If you measure performance and it turns out that keeping idle threads around somehow needs to be addressed, then look into it.

What you are asking for has already been implemented in ThreadPoolExecutor. From the documentation:
Core and maximum pool sizes
A ThreadPoolExecutor will automatically adjust the pool size (see getPoolSize()) according to the bounds set by corePoolSize (see getCorePoolSize()) and maximumPoolSize (see getMaximumPoolSize()). [...] By setting corePoolSize and maximumPoolSize the same, you create a fixed-size thread pool. By setting maximumPoolSize to an essentially unbounded value such as Integer.MAX_VALUE, you allow the pool to accommodate an arbitrary number of concurrent tasks. Most typically, core and maximum pool sizes are set only upon construction, but they may also be changed dynamically using setCorePoolSize(int) and setMaximumPoolSize(int).
[...]
Reclamation
[...] You can configure a pool to allow all unused threads to eventually die by setting appropriate keep-alive times, using a lower bound of zero core threads and/or setting allowCoreThreadTimeOut(boolean).
So all you need to do is to create a ThreadPoolExecutor with a core size of 4, a maximum pool size of 8 and set the keep-alive time to 60 seconds.
